# What's the syntax of using multiple handlers in Happstack?

Tags: haskell, happstack, hdbc

Sorry for my basic question, but I'm new to Haskell.

I'm following [this example](http://happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/RqData.html#rqdatapost) to receive some values from a request body, but my server also serves static files from a directory using the following code:

```
fileServing :: ServerPart Response
fileServing = serveDirectory EnableBrowsing ["index.html"] "./Path/"

mainFunc = simpleHTTP nullConf $ msum [ 
                                        fileServing                                     
                                      ]
```

I added the below code to my library but I'm not sure where to use the `handlers` function, because I already have an `msum` in the `mainFunc`.

```
handlers :: ServerPart Response
handlers =
    do decodeBody myPolicy
       msum [ 
               myGetData
            ]

myGetData :: ServerPart Response
myGetData =
    do method POST
       username <- look "username"
       password <- look "password"
       ok $ toResponse (username ++ ", " ++ password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fileServing`, `myGetData`, `msum [fileServing]`, `msum [myGetData]` and `handlers` all have `ServerPart Response` type, which is the type of what you are passing to `simpleHTTP nullConf` in `mainFunc`. That being so, you probably want...

```
mainFunc = simpleHTTP nullConf handlers

-- etc.

handlers :: ServerPart Response
handlers =
    do decodeBody myPolicy
       msum [ fileServing
            , myGetData
            ]
```

`msum` here combines a list of handlers into a single handler (note that also means `msum` on a list with a single handler is redundant).